# Is there a trick to help Winnie the Pooh score homeruns?

Tags: winnie-the-pooh

[Winnie the Pooh](http://disney.kids.yahoo.co.jp/game/pooh.html) is a Flash-based game made by Disney and intended for Japanese children.

[image: Stages]

To cite [the description](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?p=46017996&postcount=1) of the game:

> The goal is to make the indicated amount of homeruns with a set amount
>   of pitches and fouls/non homeruns will subtract from the amount of
>   pitches you have. Each level has a increased amount of homeruns with
>   increasing difficulty of pitches. And at the level select screen there
>   is a button for upgrades.

[image: Winnie the Pooh]

While being able to finish the first stage, I am stuck against Piglet and I noticed that even after playing the same level several times, I have a hard time scoring a home run: the ball goes too much to the left, too much to the right, or not far enough.

Does the same input always result in the same output? If so, is there a strategy (I have noticed a visual green cue)? Or is there a random factor in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must hit the ball almost exactly on target. The ball must be placed as close to the green circle as possible when you swing. You will have to position yourself both horizontally and vertically correctly, and time your swing well.

There is also an upgrade screen where you can boost your power, accuracy, and speed. To access it, click the button on the lower right of the stage selection screen. These upgrades are imperative for completing later stages.

This game is very unusually hard for a children's game. Proceed with caution... piglet is only the beginning.

Comment: I have trouble finding the correct vertical position. But other than that, I understand your tips. Thanks!